# Wordpress Users not Listing

Tags: php, wordpress

For some reason, I cant seem to get any users from the following code... Is there anything wrong with it? All I get is "FUBAR"...

```
function current_user_access_level($type, $object) {
    if ( $type == 'users' ) {
        if ( empty( $object) ) {
            $return = 'FUBAR';
        } else {
            $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
            $user_id = $current_user->ID;
            $user_access_level = get_user_meta($user_id, 'wpcf-member-access-level', true);
            switch ($user_access_level) {
                case 1:
                    $return = '1'; 
                    break;
                case 2;
                    $return = '2'; 
                    break;
                case 3;
                    $return = '3'; 
                    break;
                case 4;
                    $return = '4'; 
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    return $return;
}
```

Comment: You get FUBAR when `$object` is empty; how are you calling this code? Presumably whatever you're passing in is incorrect

Comment: on a side note,  if $type != 'users',  you will be returning an unset variable `$return`.  You may want to initialize `$return = null` , in the beginning

Comment: @Jeff It should return a list of Wordpress users, so FUBAR could me 0 or NULL, it still returns zero users...

Comment: @andrewsi When I remove the if statement, all users are listing...

Comment: @iamchriswick - you're passing in two paramters. You don't use `$type` at all, and the only think you're using `$object` for is your check. Why do you need to pass these in, if you're not using them. Also - there's nothing in this code that prints anything, so I assume you're doing something with the return value? Have you checked that what you're returning from this code is correct?